# Slopegraph with too many observations

Tags: self-study, data-visualization, pre-post-comparison

Currently, I am studying the book "storytelling with data - Cole Nussbaumer Knaflic" to learn about data visualization. Now I am learning why the slope graph can be very helpful. If you have too many observations it could become a mess. The book says the following:

> If many of the lines are overlapping, a slopegraph may not work,
> though in some cases you can still emphasize a single series at a time
> with success.

I can imagine that with 100 observations, a slopegraph can become a little bit of a mess. Unfortunately, the book doesn't tell a good alternative for that problem. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
set.seed(7)
df <- data.frame(status = rep(c('pre', 'post'), each = 100),
                 value = runif(200, 0, 1),
                 group = rep(c(1:100), n = 2))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(status), y = value, group = group)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  labs(x = 'Status') +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

So I was wondering what could be a good alternative to a slopegraph to show many observations while keeping the same information as a slopegraph offers?

Comment: What do you want to show ultimately with your graph?

Comment: Hi @JJJ, I would like to show the change from pre to post, so what the changes are.

Comment: Have you considered a standard scatterplot of (pre, post) observations?

Comment: @Quinten Note that the plot is simply showing a set of differences as slopes (taking pre-post distance on the x-axis as 1). That visual comparison of slopes may be better done as their raw values (post-value-pre-value). Beyond that, but in a similar vein, a Tukey mean/difference  plot may be relevant (medical people tend to call it a Bland-Altman plot)

Comment: The term "slope graph" is from Edward Tufte, but the idea is much older under names like profile plot or parallel coordinates, and indeed tacit in any plot of two or more time series. But slope graphs have point largely to the extent that (1) each object is named so that you can follow changes using subject-matter knowledge  (2) there is an intelligible pattern or at least some interesting details. If (1) is absent, (2) must be true for such a plot to be useful, The example is random noise, but they key question is then what holds for anyone's real data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered in comments:

> Have you considered a standard scatterplot of (pre, post)
> observations?
>
> – whuber

> Note that the plot is simply showing a set of differences as slopes
> (taking pre-post distance on the x-axis as 1). That visual comparison
> of slopes may be better done as their raw values
> (post-value-pre-value). Beyond that, but in a similar vein, a Tukey
> mean/difference plot may be relevant (medical people tend to call it a
> Bland-Altman plot)
>
> – Glen_b